# nginx ldap module error

Tags: ssl, nginx, ldap

I was trying to include the LDAP module to nginx. I could add the module and make install nginx successfully, however, while trying to restart the nginx, I get the following error:

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /var/www/conf/nginx.conf -t

nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.so" failed (/usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.so: undefined symbol: ngx_ssl_handshake) in /var/www/conf/nginx.conf:11
nginx: configuration file /var/www/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

When I looked at the ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c file, I found that there is a call to this function. I am not sure where is this function being called from. Is there any other library that needs to be installed?

I have already installed the following:

```
openssl-devel.x86_64
openldap-devel.x86_64
zlib-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that I wasn't configuring nginx with the http_ssl_module option.
To make it work, I re-configured the nginx as:

```
./configure --add-module=/path/to/ldap_module --with-http_ssl_module
```

And then issued make and install commands. The ngx_ssl_handshake error got removed.